# ExportAsFixedFormat is deleting VBA buttons on only one sheet

Tags: vba, excel, export-to-pdf

So I have a spreadsheet that gets updated frequently throughout the day. For tracking purposes, I want to export a few of the tabs to a PDF.  Simple enough, just select the sheets I want and used `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat`.  For some reason, one of those sheets is getting the VBA buttons on there to disappear.  Any ideas what is going on so I can make this stop?

Some details:

- When I go to draw on new buttons, unless I make the size massive (15+ columns and rows large), I can't see a button.  And even then, the button font is huge (despite excel saying it's size 10)
- `Activesheet.Buttons.Count` is returning the correct count
- Looping through all buttons on the sheet, visible property is true
- One other sheet being saved in the pdf has buttons on it, they are unaffected
- Stepping through the debugger one line at a time results in the buttons shrinking, running it flat out makes them tiny
- I've tried to loop through all buttons and make them be a fixed size, no help

Code snippet:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PrintSheets()).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    fileName:=path & fileName, _
    Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Where `PrintSheets()` returns an array of sheet names (strings), `path` and `fileName` are defined above (strings) in the sub using input boxes.

Edit:  Tried saving the tabs as a pdf manually, the smaller button scenario still happened. Seems to be tied to the saving of the button, not so much my macro code.

Edit 2:  Since the exporting a pdf only removed the buttons from that one sheet, I modified my code to activate that sheet before exporting.  This gives me the error where the buttons get smaller, but still visible.  I then put a loop in my code to resize the buttons before finishing.  While this may be a solution to my exact case, I hope there is a true answer out there for this in all cases.

Edit 3:  Including some of the discussion below.  When I loop through each sheet individually, activate it, and export to pdf, the buttons will stay visible on all sheets that have them.  Closing excel completely and re-opening the workbook will bring the buttons back.

Comment: Is it the sheet where the code is assigned to? Try to copy the sheet in question and check if that behaviour repeats itself on a different sheet with the same data

Comment: I've inserted a new sheet and tried to just copy over the formulas/formats/tables in the sheet, the problem still persists.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did your code have the same Problem with the additional sheet, or was the problem still only in the original one?

Comment: it seems the exporting PDF will remove the buttons from view on any screen that isn't the active screen.  `Activesheet.Buttons.Count` returns an accurate count though.

Comment: By *active screen* you mean *active sheet*? If so, try to set each sheet active before printing it

Comment: trying to save 6 tabs into one pdf, otherwise I would do that.

Comment: Are you able to print each sheet separately and get the desired result?

Comment: probably, assuming I set each sheet to be active before i print it.  It looks like the buttons are still in memory somewhere.  Closing excel entirely and re-opening the workbook will bring the buttons back.

Comment: I see. Try to confirm the sheet by sheet print so that we can close in on the reason of the error.

Comment: Ran the loop, was able to print each sheet individually without the buttons going missing.  Also, I tested using a FormControl button vs an ActiveX button, and it did not matter.  I'm not sure if it makes a difference but the buttons are set to no print (print object not selected).